# pattern matching and applying a function, not working as expected

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence

Consider the following code

```
G[x, y] /. a_[b__] -> Total[a @@@ Permutations[List[b]]]
```

I expect it to give

```
G[x, y]+G[y,x]
```

But it gives,

```
G[x, y]
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: If you use `RuleDelayed`, e.g. `G[x, y] /. a_[b__] :> Total[a @@@ Permutations[List[b]]]` it will work. Use `yourcode//Trace` to see what is happening.

Comment: Permutation is evaluated first. check G[x, y] /. a_[b__] -> Total[a @@@ Permutations[List[b]]]//Trace. Other that that, why not simply:Total@Permutations[G[x, y]]

Comment: your comments were very helpful. Thanks for your time.
I knew about the easier way of doing it, but I wanted to understand the way this code works, and Trace is indeed very helpful to diagnose that